# Sonar false positive immutability rule

Tags: java, sonarqube, immutability, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

Hopefully someone can help clarifying this.

Consider having the following exception type:

```
public class SomeException extends RuntimeException {
    private List<String> messages;

    public SomeException(List<String> messages) {
        this.messages = Collections.unmodifiableList(messages);
    }

    public List<String> getMessages() {
        return this.messages;
    }
}
```

For the `getMessages` method Sonar says that the immutability rule is violated and I should return a copy of the internal list.

However, there is no need for that because Sonar should figure out that the internal `List` could've been set only via the constructor, thus through calling `Collections.unmodifiableList` which is by nature cannot be modified.

Has anyone encountered such an issue?

Personally I don't really want to copy the list again.